# Search and replace img tag inside td with the alt value

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
var full_data = table.innerHTML;
console.log(full_data);
```

Output:

```
<caption>For demo purpose: CP</caption><colgroup align="center"></colgroup><colgroup align="left"></colgroup><colgroup span="2" align="center"></colgroup><colgroup span="3" align="center"></colgroup><thead valign="top"><tr><th>ID<br>no</th><th>Name</th><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col<br>3</th><th>Col<br>4</th><th>Col<br>5</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>1200</td><td style="background-color: #00f; color: #fff">Testing</td><td></td><td></td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>*</td></tr><tr><td>1250</td><td style="font-weight: bold"><a href="http://www.google.com/">http://www.google.com/</a></td><td>X</td><td></td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>1251</td><td><img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png" alt="google" title="google title" widht="20px" height="20px"></td><td>X</td><td></td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>1252</td><td>Windows 98</td><td>X</td><td></td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>1253</td><td>Windows 2000</td><td>X</td><td></td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>1254</td><td>Windows ME</td><td>X</td><td></td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>1255</td><td>Hebrew</td><td>X</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>1256</td><td>Arabic</td><td>X</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>1257</td><td>Baltic</td><td>X</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>1361</td><td>Hindi</td><td>X</td><td></td><td></td><td>**</td><td>X</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td>437</td><td>MS-DOS</td><td></td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>708</td><td>Say what again</td><td></td><td>X</td><td></td><td></td><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>709</td><td>CP</td><td></td><td>X</td><td></td><td></td><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>710</td><td>What</td><td></td><td>X</td><td></td><td></td><td>X</td></tr><tr><td>720</td><td>OK Done</td><td></td><td>X</td><td></td><td></td><td>X</td></tr></tbody>
```

In the output there is a `td` as

`<td><img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png" alt="google" title="google title" widht="20px" height="20px"></td>`

I want to search for such cases where there is a `img` inside `td` and then replace this complete `img` tag with its `alt` value. So the above will become.

`<td>google</td>`

How can this be done using JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: Please indent your posted code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`replaceWith()`](https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)**:

```
$('td > img[alt]').each(function() {
    if($(this).siblings().length === 0) $(this).replaceWith($(this).attr('alt'));
});
```

Comment: maybe you could use as selector: `'td > img[alt]'`

Comment: @A.Wolff - Tks. That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$('td').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('img').length) {
        $(this).html($(this).attr('alt'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use regex is lighter

`full_data.replace(new RegExp("<td>.*?alt=\"(.*?)\".*?</td>"), "<td>$1</td>")`

Comment: Your regex is not working, check this: http://jsfiddle.net/chankeypathak/7cwZ9/7/

Comment: assume that each img has attr alt, use `full_data.replace(new RegExp("<img.*?alt=\"(.*?)\".*?>", "g"), "$1")` instead